# Compiling gcc itself, on windows for windows targetting arm: "cc1.exe: out of memory allocating 2278450599 bytes"

Tags: windows, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I am following 
http://www.mingw.org/wiki/hostedcrosscompilerhowto
and issuing

> make all-gcc | tee make-c-only.log 2>&1

yields

```
gcc -c   -O2 -pipe -DIN_GCC -DCROSS_COMPILE  -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings
-Wstrict-p rototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -pedantic -Wno-long-long    -DHAVE_CONFIG_H    -I . -I. -I../../../../gcc-core-3.4.2-20040916-1-src/gcc-3.4.2-20040916-1/gcc -I../ ../../../gcc-core-3.4.2-20040916-1-src/gcc-3.4.2-20040916-1/gcc/.
-I../../../../ gcc-core-3.4.2-20040916-1-src/gcc-3.4.2-20040916-1/gcc/../include 
insn-modes.c
-o insn-modes.o

**cc1.exe: out of memory allocating 2278450599 bytes** make[1]: ***
[insn-modes.o] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory
`/e/Lorin/gcc/aufWindows7MingwOrgHowto/build/arm-elf/ gcc/gcc' make:
*** [all-gcc] Error 2
```

I do have 2GB of free memory.

EDIT: Will try to use 64bit mingw-w64 5.2.0 with the last MSYS-20111123.zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was using a **32bit** distribution of mingw the compiler cannot allocate beyond 2GB of RAM for itsself, regardless of whether this was a bug or not.

A solution to this error was to use a newer version of gcc for windows ie. the one from the "**mingw-w64**" project.

Note: Don't get yourself confused, the mingw-w64 project **also has a 32bit** version available **even though** the project is **called** mingw-w**64**